# Reducing code duplication with methods that use NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have these two class methods, each one with it's predicate. They're function is to hold information that is going to be displayed in a mapKit and in a UITable View. But I see repeated code, except for the predicate; my question is: how can I avoid these repetitions?

```
+ (NSArray*)spotType:(NSString*)type{
    NSPersistentContainer *persistenceContainer = [AppDelegate sharedDelegate].persistentContainer;
    NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type =%@", type];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = persistenceContainer.viewContext;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Spot"];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"[Spot spotType] -> %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return nil;
    }
    return result;
}

+ (NSArray*)spotWithType:(NSString*)type{
    NSPersistentContainer *persistenceContainer = [AppDelegate sharedDelegate].persistentContainer;
    NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (type = %@)", type];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = persistenceContainer.viewContext;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Spot"];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"[Spot spotWithType] -> %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return nil;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You can write `+ (NSArray*)spotWithType:(NSString*)type present:(BOOL)present`. In it you do the same, except for the predicate, checking its value and creating the correct predicate. Then `+ (NSArray*)spotType:(NSString*)type{return [self spotWithType:type present:YES]}` and `+ (NSArray*)spotWithType:(NSString*)type{return [self spotWithType:type present:NO];}`? You can add a `NSError` parameter if you want to log differently for your `executeFetchRequest:error:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic way of reducing code duplication is placing the common code into a shared private method:

```
- (NSArray*)getSpotType:(NSString*)type withPredicate:(NSString*) pred andMessage:(NSString*)message {
    NSPersistentContainer *persistenceContainer = [AppDelegate sharedDelegate].persistentContainer;
    NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:pred, type];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = persistenceContainer.viewContext;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Spot"];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(message, [error localizedDescription]);
        return nil;
    }
    return result;
}
- (NSArray*)spotType:(NSString*)type {
    return [MyClass getSpotType:type withPredicate:@"type =%@" andMessage:@"[Spot spotType] -> %@"];
}
- (NSArray*)spotWithType:(NSString*)type {
    return [MyClass getSpotType:type withPredicate:@"NOT (type = %@)" andMessage:@"[Spot spotWithType] -> %@"];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :)